# How to prevent solr from decoding a url while indexing?

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I'm using Solrj to index document in Solr, one of the field being url. While creating the solr document and subsequently passing it to a SolrServer, I'm not doing any explicit decoding, in order to keep the original format of the url. But, once it's indexed, the urls are decoded.

Here's a test example which contains apostrophe.

```
http://test.com/test/Help/What%e2%80%99s_N1
```

In solr index, it's being decoded to

```
http://test.com/test/Help/What's_N1
```

Here's a sample code :

```
SolrServer solrServer = new StreamingUpdateSolrServer(solrPostUrl, solrQueueSize, solrThreads);
SolrInputDocument solrDoc = new SolrInputDocument();
solrDoc.addField("url", "http://test.com/test/Help/What%e2%80%99s_N1");
UpdateResponse solrResponse = solrServer.add(solrDoc);
```

I looked into the SolrInputDocument object, it does have the right format, i.e. the encoded version.

I'll appreciate if someone can provide pointers to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of your tokenizers

> A good general purpose tokenizer that strips many extraneous
>   characters and sets token types to meaningful values. Token types are
>   only useful for subsequent token filters that are type-aware of the
>   same token types. There aren't any filters that use
>   StandardTokenizer's types.

about standardTokenizer

check it out [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters)

you can change all of this behaviour in the solr/schema.xml